# "You are attempting to open a file of type 'Application extension' on every right-click

Tags: windows-7

Every time I right-click on any of:

- A file in Windows Explorer
- A pinned app on the taskbar
- An icon in the system tray
- An image in my browser

instead of a context menu, I immediately get the following message:

[image: You are attempting to open a file of type Application Extension]

This also happens when I right-click on, for example, a style in the MS Word style inspector.

How can I debug what's going on here?

Comment: There are various articles that explain how to reset the default file association on Windows.  Have you tried doing that?  Update your question once you have done that.

Comment: Sounds like a broken Shell Extension. Open the file with some application to see which DLL it is referring to. Update your question with that information.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think it's an issue with file associations. I'm quite clear in the original post that it happens in many different right-click contexts. (Notice, not on double left-click, which would then suggest a file association issue.)

Comment: @DanielB This issue occurs right-clicking on *any* file, and also system tray icons and taskbar shortcuts. Could you specify which file I should open, and in which application.

Comment: @LondonRob - If you are not willing to try to restore file associations then I won't investigate any further.  I have to at least know file associations are correct in order to eliminate some other issues.  The reason I suspect a file association problem is, the system is attempting to open .dll file extension, with a program.  Which means the file extension is associated with a program which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @Ramhound could you clarify which file associations I should be interested in? Or can you reset them all somehow?

Comment: At first I also though about a broken shell extension but that doesn't make sense with right-clicking in the browser (unless maybe if the browser is IE) or in MS Word.

Comment: @LondonRob You should simply continue with the workflow by selecting “Open with” and then something that doesn’t complain and shows the filename. Like Notepad.

Comment: @LondonRob - Yes, I would like you to restore the default file associations for all file extensions.  As I pointed out numerous articles on how to do that, articles, that even provide a .reg file to precisely that.